# disable Lock & Edit mode in WebLogic

Tags: weblogic

I have a code that install a new application in a WL server.
My problem is that if I'm in a "Lock & Edit" mode it wont pass untill i will change the mode by clicking in the console on the "Activate Changes" button.
Is there a way to control that option via Java some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control Weblogic using the Weblogic Scripting Tool (WLST).

WLST can be embedded in Java using the weblogic.jar, you can find it in your Weblogic installation directory.

WLST commands can be called using these packages:

```
import org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter;
import weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter;
```

an example on how to convert WLST script to java code can be found here:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10757646

Comment: Do you know a wat to get the state of the "lock & edit" option using the wlst?
There is an option of "GET" in WLST but you need an attribute. What attribute i need to use in order to get the state of "lock & edit" mode?

Comment: Why not just use save() if you want to activate, or stopEdit() if you don't want changes to be saved? this way you will exit editing mode.